# What is the time complexity of sum() in Python?

Tags: python, sum, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the sum() function?

Comment: Dude, how can anyone tell you the time complexity when you don't provide the algorithm.

Comment: Lemme guess: O(n) where n = # of values.

Comment: Try it with two values and two hundred million values. If the second takes longer than the first, it's probably not O(1).

Comment: Ooo ... I would like an O(1) sum algorithm.  I suppose if you know the sequence, you can do that in O(1) sometimes :) (but, of course, python doesn't know anything about the properties of your sequence, so It's unlikely that optimization will ever make it into the language ;)

Comment: You could always maintain a running sum as an attribute of the sequence, if you're willing to do the work on insertion and removal. I can't say I see the point unless you're repeatedly summing large sequences (much more often than you're inserting or removing elements), but it would allow O(1).

Comment: So if I left out my two assumptions, I wouldn't get 4 down votes? How is this not an useful question... I didn't see another post with this answer.

Comment: @duffymo pretty good guess!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It will make Theta(n) `next` calls on the iterator, and Theta(n) additions, where `n` is the number of items you're summing.

That's as specific as you can be for the time complexity of an algorithm that calls unknown code. If the time taken for each addition depends on `n` (as for example it would when summing `list`s, like `sum(list(range(i)) for i in range(n))`), then that's going to affect the overall time complexity.

Answer (score 16):

It's got to be O(n) for a large list of integers.

Answer (score 5):

1. It depends on your data structure. For a flat list, you cannot do better than O(n) because you have to look at each item in the list to add them up.
2. When in doubt, try it out: `import profile` is your friend.