# Why do I encounter Time Limit Exceeded in this Exclusion-Inclusion Based Question?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, big-o

I recently participated in an event(Starters 99) and came across [this question](https://www.codechef.com/START99D/problems/ONEFROMK)

Here is my initial attempt which I believe is **correct logically but resulted in a TLE**

```
for j in range(int(input())):
     n=int(input())
     arr=sorted(list(map(int,input().split())))
     lst=[]
     for k in range(1,n+1):
         lst.append(sum(arr[k-1:]))
     print(" ".join(list(map(str,lst))))
```

**My latest working solution**:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    l=int(input())
    arr=sorted(list(map(int,input().split())))
    s=sum(arr)
    n=[s]
    for k in range(0,l-1):
        s-=arr[k]
        n.append(s)
    print(" ".join(list(map(str,n))))
```

**So could anybody help me out by explaining what makes my initial code different from my latest with respect to TLE issue** ?

PS:I also just passed out from high school and haven't gone to college yet. So I don't have a thorough grasp on Space Time Complexity. However I do understand definitions and graphical analysis of big O notation. But have no idea on how to calculate that with respect to this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference between the two solutions is that the initial solution's time complexity was higher due to the nested loop [time complexity of O(n^2)], whereas the latest solution has a better time complexity [O(n)] due to the linear calculation of cumulative sum.

Comment: Thank you very much Ishaan! Just 1 more doubt. 

So in the 2nd case, although there is nested loop, can we intuitively say its effect is not felt due to linear calculation of cumulative sum (which has a complexity of O(1)). 

Whereas in the 1st case, the effect of nested loop is considered as in each iteration we call a function i.e. sum() which has a complexity O(n) .

Comment: Yup, you are absolutely correct. In the initial solution, the nested loop and slicing lead to repeated calculations of sums, resulting in a time complexity of O(n^2). However, the latest solution efficiently calculates cumulative sums with a linear time complexity of O(n), as it updates the sum in constant time (O(1)) within a single loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of `sum()` is `O(N)` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20135093). Since you're calling `sum()` in each iteration, it results in a total complexity of `O(N + (N-1) + (N-2)... + 1) ~= O(N^2)`.

In your updated approach, you're using an array to pre-compute the sums, so accessing the sum during an iteration boils down to `O(1)`, and it results in a total complexity of `O(N)`.

Comment: Thank you Abhinav! so using my intuition, so time complexity only depends on what is there inside the for loops right? If there are many for loops but we are only precomputing the sum like in my updated approach, the time complexity would still remain of O(N) right?

Comment: @singleslit instead of thinking in terms of loops, think in terms of operations. Doing 100 operations each in 100 iterations = 10000 operations. Doing 1000 operations each in 10 iterations = 10000 operations.

Answer (score 0):

With judicious use of assignment expressions (a.k.a. the walrus operator) you can make your code a little more concise. You can also avoid the str.join() call for the output by just unpacking the list as follows:

```
def main():
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        input() # value not needed - just consume it
        a = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
        output = [_sum := sum(a)]
        for x in a[:-1]:
            output.append(_sum := _sum - x)
        print(*output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Wow great buddy, can you also explain what is the time complexity here?
'output.append()' will have O(1) and O(N) for inner loop. So basically of O(N) right?
Please correct me if I am wrong.